# a way to connect many signal in one godot

Tags: signals, game-development, godot

I have to connect many signals (on_mouse_entered and on_mouse_exited) to different labels. These labels represent certain sites on a map in a game. On mouse entered makes show the label, instead on mouse exited it hides it. I was asking myself if there is a way to link all these labels for example to something like a class and link the signals once for all. Thanks to who wants reply.

Comment: You could extend the Label class and create your own MapSiteLabel class.  Then you could put the logic for mouse_entered and mouse_exited in there and just use that class/control where you're currently using label.

Comment: @HumanWrites That is certainly a way to do it. Would you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

One potential solution for your problem would be to extend the Label class and create your own MapSiteLabel class.  You could then put the logic for mouse_entered and mouse_exited in there and just use that class/control where you're currently using label.

*(Just adding my comment from above as an answer so that it might help anyone else who comes across this question)*